# Video Conference through webrtc

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc

I am doing a project on Video Conference where the users can chat online through text and video. The text is exchanged between the two particular users but the video is getting broadcast-ed.The video and audio should get transmitted to a particular user. Please help me to resolve this problem. I am attaching the project. I have done with **visual studio 2010 and webrtc**. the webform is **Video**
 Thanks in advance.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://Video.com:1337/');  // change the IP address to your websocket server
  var stunServer = "stun.l.google.com:19302";
  var sourcevid = document.getElementById('sourcevid');
  var remotevid = document.getElementById('remotevid');
  var localStream = null;
  var remoteStream;
  var peerConn = null;
  var started = false;
  var isRTCPeerConnection = true;
  var mediaConstraints = { 'mandatory': {
      'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
      'OfferToReceiveVideo': true
  }
  };

  var logg = function (s) { console.log(s); };

  //for text chat
  var chatInput;
  var chatArea;
  var chatNick;
  var chatoNick;
  var chatFrameObj;
  myMid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
  myMid = "'" + myMid + "'";
  chatInput = document.getElementById("chatInputText");
  chatNick = document.getElementById("chatNick");
  chatoNick = document.getElementById("chatoNick");
  chatFrameObj = document.getElementById("chatFrame");
  chatNick.value = myMid;


  // send the message to websocket server
  function sendMessage(message) {
      var mymsg = JSON.stringify(message);
      logg("SEND: " + mymsg);
      socket.send(mymsg);
  }

  function createPeerConnection() {
      try {
          logg("Creating peer connection");
          var servers = [];
          servers.push({ 'url': 'stun:' + stunServer });
          var pc_config = { 'iceServers': servers };
          peerConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(pc_config);
          peerConn.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
      } catch (e) {
          try {
              peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection('STUN ' + stunServer, onIceCandidate00);
              isRTCPeerConnection = false;
          } catch (e) {
              logg("Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: " + e.message);
          }
      }

      peerConn.onaddstream = onRemoteStreamAdded;
      peerConn.onremovestream = onRemoteStreamRemoved;
  }

  // when remote adds a stream, hand it on to the local video element
  function onRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
      logg("Added remote stream");
      remotevid.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
  }

  function waitForRemoteVideo() {
      if (remoteStream.videoTracks.length === 0 || remotevid.currentTime > 0) {
          transitionToActive();
      } else {
          setTimeout(waitForRemoteVideo, 100);
      }
  }

  function transitionToActive() {
      remotevid.style.opacity = 1;
      card.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(180deg)";
      setTimeout(function () { sourcevid.src = ""; }, 500);
      setStatus("<input type=\"button\" id=\"hangup\" value=\"Hang up\" onclick=\"onHangup()\" />");
  }

  // when remote removes a stream, remove it from the local video element
  function onRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
      logg("Remove remote stream");
      remotevid.src = "";
  }

  function onIceCandidate(event) {
      if (event.candidate) {
          sendMessage({ type: 'candidate',
              label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
              id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
              candidate: event.candidate.candidate, mid: myMid, nick: chatNick.value, tonick: chatoNick.value
          });
      } else {
          logg("End of candidates.");
      }
  }

  function onIceCandidate00(candidate, moreToFollow) {
      if (candidate) {
          sendMessage({ type: 'candidate', label: candidate.label, candidate: candidate.toSdp(), mid: myMid, nick: chatNick.value, tonick: chatoNick.value });
      }
      if (!moreToFollow) {
          logg("End of candidates.");
      }
  }

  // start the connection upon user request
  function connect() {
      if (!started && localStream)
      {
          document.getElementById('anim').style.visibility = 'visible';
          console.log("Creating PeerConnection.");
          createPeerConnection();
          logg('Adding local stream...');
          peerConn.addStream(localStream);
          started = true;
          logg("isRTCPeerConnection: " + isRTCPeerConnection);

          //create offer
          if (isRTCPeerConnection) {
              peerConn.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null, mediaConstraints);
          } else {
              var offer = peerConn.createOffer(mediaConstraints);
              peerConn.setLocalDescription(peerConn.SDP_OFFER, offer);
              sendMessage({ type: 'offer', sdp: offer.toSdp() });
              peerConn.startIce();
          }
          // __doPost('btnconnect', 'OnClick');
          document.getElementById('<%=btnconnect.ClientID%>').fireEvent("onclick");
      } else {
          alert("Local stream not running yet.");
      }
  }

  // accept connection request
  socket.addEventListener("message", onMessage, false);
  function onMessage(evt) {
      logg("RECEIVED: " + evt.data);
      if (isRTCPeerConnection)
          processSignalingMessage(evt.data);
      else
          processSignalingMessage00(evt.data);
  }

  function processSignalingMessage(message) {
      var msg = JSON.parse(message);

      if (msg.type === 'offer') {

          if (!started && localStream) {
              createPeerConnection();
              logg('Adding local stream...');
              peerConn.addStream(localStream);
              started = true;
              logg("isRTCPeerConnection: " + isRTCPeerConnection);


              if (isRTCPeerConnection) {
                  //set remote description
                  peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg));
                  //create answer
                  console.log("Sending answer to peer.");
                  peerConn.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null, mediaConstraints);
              } else {
                  //set remote description
                  peerConn.setRemoteDescription(peerConn.SDP_OFFER, new SessionDescription(msg.sdp));
                  //create answer
                  var offer = peerConn.remoteDescription;
                  var answer = peerConn.createAnswer(offer.toSdp(), mediaConstraints);
                  console.log("Sending answer to peer.");
                  setLocalAndSendMessage00(answer);
              }
          }

      } else if (msg.type === 'answer' && started) {
          peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg));
      } else if (msg.type === 'candidate' && started) {
          var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({ sdpMLineIndex: msg.label, candidate: msg.candidate });
          peerConn.addIceCandidate(candidate);
      } else if ((msg.type == 'chat') && ((msg.tonick == chatNick.value) || (msg.tonick == ''))) {
          addChatMsg(msg.nick, msg.cid, msg.data);
      }
      else if (msg.type === 'bye' && started) {
          onRemoteHangUp();
      }
  }

  function processSignalingMessage00(message) {
      var msg = JSON.parse(message);

      // if (msg.type === 'offer')  --> will never happened since isRTCPeerConnection=true initially
      if (msg.type === 'answer' && started) {
          peerConn.setRemoteDescription(peerConn.SDP_ANSWER, new SessionDescription(msg.sdp));
      } else if (msg.type === 'candidate' && started) {
          var candidate = new IceCandidate(msg.label, msg.candidate);
          peerConn.processIceMessage(candidate);
      } else if (msg.type === 'bye' && started) {
          onRemoteHangUp();
      }
  }

  function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
      peerConn.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
      sendMessage(sessionDescription);
  }

  function setLocalAndSendMessage00(answer) {
      peerConn.setLocalDescription(peerConn.SDP_ANSWER, answer);
      sendMessage({ type: 'answer', sdp: answer.toSdp() });
      peerConn.startIce();
  }

  function onRemoteHangUp() {
      logg("Remote Hang up.");
      closeSession();
  }

  function onHangUp() {
      logg("Hang up.");
      document.getElementById('anim').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      if (started) {
          sendMessage({ type: 'bye' });
          closeSession();
          __doPost('btnhangup', 'OnClick');
      }
  }

  function closeSession() {
      peerConn.close();
      peerConn = null;
      started = false;
      remotevid.src = "";
  }

  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      if (started) {
          sendMessage({ type: 'bye' });
      }
  }

  function startVideo()
  {
      // Replace the source of the video element with the stream from the camera
      try 
      {
          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }, successCallback, errorCallback);
      }
      catch (e) 
      {
          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia("video,audio", successCallback, errorCallback);
      }
      function successCallback(stream) 
      {
          sourcevid.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
          sourcevid.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(180deg)";
          localStream = stream;
      }
      function errorCallback(error) 
      {
          logg('An error occurred: [CODE ' + error.code + ']');
      }
  }

  function stopVideo() {
      sourcevid.src = "";
  }

  function sendChatMsg()
  {
      var classIdx = myMid.substr(myMid.length - 1, 1);
      if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
          if (chatInput.value.length < 1) {
              return;
          }
          console.log("msg will be sent -> " + chatInput.value);
          addChatMsg("Me", classIdx, chatInput.value);
          sendMessage({ type: "chat", data: chatInput.value, mid: myMid, nick: chatNick.value, tonick: chatoNick.value, cid: classIdx });

         //chatInput.value = '';
      }
  }

  function addChatMsg(id, classIdx, msg) {
      var msgP = document.createElement("span");
      var idSpan = document.createElement("span");
      idSpan.className = "member" + classIdx;
      idSpan.innerText = id;
      var msgSpan = document.createElement("span");
      msgSpan.innerText = msg + "\r\n";
      var delimSpan = document.createElement("span");
      delimSpan.innerText = " : ";
      msgP.appendChild(idSpan);
      msgP.appendChild(delimSpan);
      msgP.appendChild(msgSpan);
      chatFrame.document.body.appendChild(msgP);
      chatFrame.document.body.scrollTop = 999999;
  }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? What part of the project is not working?

Comment: yes, what is the actual issue that is occurring?

Comment: The problem is video is getting transferred to all connected users from server. The video and audio should get transferred to particular user. Like from FromUserId to ToUserId. The server should send audio and video to a particular user rather than sending to all connectd users. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please close your duplicate questions. There is no need to ask the same question numerous times. Also, your issue is in your WebSocketServer implementation. It is the thing that is sending your SDP offers to everybody and exchanging them, not the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your browser whether it is enable the webrtc. 
if you use chrome, you can enable webrtc by the following way.
Open chrome, navigate to chrome://flags and enable the options as shown below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should create rooms and when a user connects to that room start the exchange between all users connected to the room, typical behavior and implementation of any webrtc platform, that way it is more secure and professional.

You can see an example in this project:
**https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection**

I hope I've helped.